# Enforcing "Solution team-shared" settings

Tags: resharper

Is there a way to **enforce** Resharper "Solution Team-Shared" settings amongst a team of developers, such that they cannot be overridden?

From my understanding of the [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Settings_Layers.html), the "Solution Personal" settings override the team shared settings.

1. How can you ensure the consistency of the settings if individual
   developers are able to override them?
2. Is it possible to enforce certain settings and leave others available to override (e.g. templates)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of doing this is to get buy in from everyone. The whole point of having the personal level is so you can have things that aren't in the team shared file. For example I often have the setting to put XML attributes on new lines whereas the team shared one doesn't have that set at all.

There is a certain amount of trust you need to have in your team not to just override everything and they shouldn't feel the need to if you've come to a group consensus on the options used.